# WPF Datagrid MVVM : Add new row through context menu/ Not able to retrieve the new row context in the command parameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, wpfdatagrid

Have a WPF Datagrid binded to a observablecollection, that it is getting populated from the database, which can be editable or non editable based on a value of a column value.

Now, would like to add a new row in the datagrid through a context menu click which is editable, although already existing rows would be non-editable (i.e., disabled).

Well this can be achievable using a data trigger on the column value and defining a converter on the binded value i.e., selectedItem to the row. Now, problem is when I add new row, my command param passed is the selectedItem i.e.,

Menu Item Code:

```
MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddClickCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"
```

So, this is the existing row (i.e., row 1) on which I clicked to add new row(row 2), so, I get the context of the existing row (i.e., row 1).

Can anybody help me get the context of the new row added i.e., row 2 through which I can set the certain flags to enable that row as editable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna add a new row to your datagrid why not simply create a add command where you add a new item to your ObservableCollection and set this new item to your selectedItem, so its selected in your datagrid.

```
   private void AddCommandExecute()
   {
       var toAdd = new MyItem();//new "row item"
       this.MyCollection.Add(toAdd);//add to collection with automatic notification
       this.MySelectedItem = toAdd;//set as selected 
   }
```

Comment: thank you!!.. This worked by setting the SelectedItem to the newly added row.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the new item in the `ObservableCollection`.

```
var myNewRow = new RowViewModel();
_rows.Add(myNewRow);
var newRowIndex = _rows.IndexOf(myNewRow);
```